# binary delete two child case

Tags: c, tree, binary-search-tree

I'm having issues with my binary tree delete function, specifically the two child case.
My delete code is as followed along with the relevant functions called with-in

```
treeNode* delete(treeNode* root, treeNode* del)
{
    treeNode *tempLeft; //node left of curr
    treeNode *tempRight; //node right of curr
    treeNode *save_node;
    treeNode *par;

    par = parent(root, del); // Get the parent of this node.

  // Take care of the case where the node to delete is a leaf node.
    if (isLeaf(del))
    {
        // Deleting the only node in the tree.
        if (par == NULL)
        {
            free(root); // free the memory for the node.
            return NULL;
        }
        // Deletes the node if it's a left child.
        if (compareDates(par->people, del->people) > 0)
        {
            free(par->left); // Free the memory for the node.
            par->left = NULL;
        }
        // Deletes the node if it's a right child.
        else
        {
            free(par->right); // Free the memory for the node.
            par->right = NULL;
        }
        return root; // Return the root of the new tree.
    }
    if (hasOnlyLeftChild(del))
    {

        // Deleting the root node of the tree.
        if (par == NULL)
        {
            save_node = del->left;
            save_node->top = 1;
            free(del); // Free the node to delete.
            return save_node; // Return the new root node of the resulting tree.
        }

        // Deletes the node if it's a left child.
        if (compareDates(par->people, del->people) > 0)
        {
            save_node = par->left; // Save the node to delete.
            par->left = save_node->left; // Readjust the parent pointer.
            free(save_node); // Free the memory for the deleted node.
        }

        // Deletes the node if it's a right child.
        else
        {
            save_node = par->right; // Save the node to delete.
            par->right = save_node->left; // Readjust the parent pointer.
            free(save_node); // Free the memory for the deleted node.
        }

        return root; // Return the root of the tree after the deletion.
    }
        // Takes care of the case where the deleted node only has a right child.
    if (hasOnlyRightChild(del))
    {
        // Node to delete is the root node.
        if (par == NULL)
        {
            save_node = del->right;
            save_node->top = 1;
            free(del);
            return save_node;
        }
        // Delete's the node if it is a left child.
        if (compareDates(par->people, del->people) > 0)
        {
            save_node = par->left;
            par->left = save_node->right;
            free(save_node);
        }
        // Delete's the node if it is a right child.
        else
        {
            save_node = par->right;
            par->right = save_node->right;
            free(save_node);
        }
        return root;
    }
    if(hasTwoChildren(del))
    {
            treeNode *temp;

            save_node = del->left;
            save_node = maxVal(save_node);
            temp = save_node;
            delete(root,save_node);
            del->people = temp->people;
            free(temp);
    }
}
```

with the two child case I find the max value in the left sub tree copy that to a temp var then call delete on the save_node then overwrite the data in del with temps data, that way I never have to worry about deleting a node with two children and fixing the pointers. In my mind that should work. The issue I'm having is that when I run delete on save_node it also is deleting the temp I created so when I go to copy temp->people in to del->people its NULL but I never touch temp when delete is run on save_node.

Is it a memory error, am I free or writing to memory I don't have that's causing me to get this odd result? is my delete code correct and I'm causing the error to happen do to a problem in another part of my code? I'm so stuck on the fact that I think the logic is right that I cant remove myself to see the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand correctly, `temp` and `save_node` are pointing to the same address in the case where it has two children.
so when you later free this address, both `temp` and `save_node` are released.

Comment: Maybe my understanding of free is incorrect then. I thought I was freeing the pointer to the address not the address it's self. So I should copy the data to temp and not the address then? I'll try that, also if that is the case should I even make a temp var? would it be okay to copy save_node's data straight the del's data then delete save_node? I'll try this and post the results. Thank you for giving me a new way to look at it.

Comment: While copying data into temp from save, data in del changes. That means its a memory error correct?

Comment: that's right. when you use free, you make the block of memory available again. the pointers that points to this block of memory are now dangling pointer, so you it's also a good idea to make those pointer null pointers. if you want to keep the data that the freed pointer referred to, you should, as you said, copy the data itself.

Comment: I was copying data incorrectly which caused a memory error. I was copying data straight to temp without ever initializing it as a node and allocating memory for it. So the whole problem was caused by my misunderstanding of what free was doing. thank you